# EPR pair and individual operations

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, bell-basis, bell-experiment

I have created an EPR pair. Let's suppose it's $(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. We both of our halves and then we move into our places.

1. If I ask you how does your half look like (mathematical expression of the state), what would be the answer? (How does my half look like?)
2. If I apply some operation to my half like maybe applying pauli $X$ gate which flips qubits, would it change anything in your half?
3. What would the combined state look like after this operation?

Comment: please ask a single, laser-focused question per post. You can ask different questions on different posts. Also, the title should reflect what (specifically) is actually been asked in the question

Comment: @glS I will try that. But I am sure this question was concept clearing. But I will do that next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The best description that I can give is a mixed state, $\rho=I/2$.

(2) If you apply a unitary operation on your half, it does not change my description of my state. If you apply a measurement on your half, my best description only updates if you tell me the measurement result.

(3) The combined state looks like $(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Now I see your answer. Thanks for answering. I have one question, can you give me an idea of how you arrive at $\rho$? What is the meaning of it?

Comment: Ok now I know why it is $I/2$. Thanks.

Comment: Still I have one more question. We have got the representation of state via density operator. So if I apply X, then how would it change in my case? (Because I don't have anything of the form $\alpha |0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$? And once I tell you that, how would you state change? Wait a second, I can do anything I want i wont matter unless I measure something and tell you right?

Comment: The description of your qubit is $\rho_A$, the description of my qubit is $\rho_B$. If you do $X$ to your qubit, yours becomes $X\rho_AX$. Mine does not change.